# Call statistics errors from MS Graph API

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We are attempting to install (CLOBBA by CODE Software) which carries out advanced reporting for MS Teams calling. In order for this to work, the software needs to retrieve data from the Microsoft Graph API. Unfortunately this is not working as we get the below error:

This is an example of one of the calls being made - https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/45578cfe-8329-48b7-ba6b-54a627b00bf4?$expand=sessions($expand=segments)

The graph API response -

```
 { "error": { "code": "BadRequest", "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: /communications/callRecords/0ff73e29-ddf6-4e6f-9963-6e7fcdf43042", "innerError": { "date": "2020-11-05T11:43:19", "request-id": "b1160328-3ce4-46c9-ae7e-da081001d367", "client-request-id": "b1160328-3ce4-46c9-ae7e-da081001d367" } } }
```

Comment: Could you please share the request Id and time stamp?

Comment: "date": "2020-11-24T12:29:26",
"request-id": "263ebee9-6a20-4a61-b0cd-9e18259714b5"

Comment: we are looking into your issue and will get back if any information needed.

Comment: Could you please check the subscription is active? if yes try to get the record with out using Odata filter.